# Trying to set 3 different ngIf's to open at different clicks

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Okay so what I want to do is when the user clicks the start timer button it opens the input so you can set your timer and the start timer button disappears then when the user clicks enter the input box will close and the cancel timer button will show when the timer is finished or the user clicks cancel and the start timer button reappears this code is inside a ngFor loop.

```js
toggleTimer: any;
toggleTimerActive: any;
toggleTimerCancel: any;
```

```html
      <div *ngFor="let time of times; let i = index" attr.data="{{time.Direction}}">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body" style="text-align: left;">
            <div class="row">
              <strong><span class="col-sm">Due in: {{time.Duein}} mins</span></strong>
              <span class="col-sm">Direction {{time.Direction}}</span>
              <span class="col-sm">Destination: {{time.Destination}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span class="col-sm">Expected Arrival {{time.Exparrival}}</span>
              <span class="col-sm">Train type {{time.Traintype}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span class="col-sm">Last Location: {{time.Lastlocation}}</span>
            </div>
            <hr />
            /* this is where I am trying to make it happen*/
            <i *ngIf="toggleTimer !== i" (click)="toggleTimer === i ? toggleTimer = null : toggleTimer = i; toggleTimerActive !== i ? toggleTimerActive = null : toggleTimerActive !== i; toggleTimerInput !== i ? toggleTimerInput = null : toggleTimerInput = true;"
              class="far fa-clock"> Set timer</i>
              <div class="timer" *ngIf="toggleTimerActive === i">
                  <i class="far fa-clock" (click)="endsTimer()"> Stop Timer</i>
                  {{remaining | time}}
              </div>
            <div class="md-form" *ngIf="toggleTimerInput === i">
              <input mdbInput type="tel" [(ngModel)]="settime" (keydown.enter)="startTimer(time.Duein); toggleTimer = i; toggleTimerInput = false;"
                class="form-control" placeholder="Set timer (In minutes)" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

At the moment when I click the start timer button, it disappears but the input doesn't show up

Comment: I am just curios does (click) event allow multiple statements to run (separated with ;)? I think its better to wrap in function rather than statements. I am sure comma (,) operator works but not sure about the semicolon (;) part

Comment: Yeah I sometimes use it if I have to call 2 functions or set a var and call a function, Commas don't work for this in angular it has a compile error if you dont use ;

Comment: Thank you very much didn't notice that it's fixed now

Comment: So is that working, can I go ahead and make the comment as an answer?

Comment: Ofcouse thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this condition always fails `toggleTimerInput !== i ? toggleTimerInput = null : toggleTimerInput = true;` Initially toggleTimerInput is undefined and not equal to 0 (assuming 0 gets assigned to i on first iteration), so null gets assigned and null never equals i so it will always be null.